# Flex Mobile - Some error

Tags: apache-flex

i got errors from these codes:

```
<cs:ConnectSessionContainer id="session" roomURL="{roomURL}" authenticator="{auth}" autoLogin="false" width="100%" height="100%" includeIn="default">
    <cs:WebCamera top="10" left="10" bottom="10" right="10"/>
</cs:ConnectSessionContainer>
```

ERRORS:

1. Could not resolve  to a component implementation.
2. Could not resolve  to a component implementation.

**BTW: When I install it on my device it wants to install Adobe Air, can i disable it in my Project?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors look like compile errors.  The error usually means that it cannot find the cs namespace.  So, you'll need to be sure to import the namespace into your component.  On the top level application, you'll usually do something like this:

```
<s:View xmlns:cs="com.directory.to.connectionSessionContainer" />
```

> BTW: When I install it on my device it wants to install Adobe Air, can
>   i disable it in my Project?

If you are using Adobe AIR 3; you can use the Captive Runtime feature to bundle the AIR Runtime w/ the app.  Then you won't have any dependencies on an external runtime.  The Flash Builder tooling does not yet support this, so you'll have to compile via the command line.

Comment: Yeah, that looks right.  However 'com.directory.to.connectionSessionContainer" should be the actual location of your ConnectSessionContainer component.

Comment: Where did you put the component when you created it? The "package" specified int he namespace declaration is just a directory structure.